# How did Sherlock know the combo for Adlers safe?

Tags: plot-explanation, sherlock

Adler said it was her measurements, but what does that mean?

Comment: Buddy, I really appreciate your innocence for asking what is meant by her measurement

Answer (score 24):

When a woman has clothes made, the tailor generally needs her measurements - the distance around in inches at chest, waist and hips. These three numbers made up the combination. Apparently, Irene Adler's measurements are 32-24-34 according to random websites.

Comment: This is correct, I have just watched the sequence again.